# Page navigation using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery

IN codeigniter I am repeatedly using the controllers to load all the templates of my page....
I have divided the page into header, top navigation, left navigation and content and footer.

This is what I do at present

```
public function get_started() {
    if (test_login()) {
        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('includes/topnav');
        $this->load->view('includes/leftbar');
        $this->load->view('login_nav/get_started');
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('errors/needlogin');      
    }
}
```

Is there any jquery-ajax helpers or plugins in codeigniter which would allow me to keep header footer and topnavigation static and allow me to load specific views using ajax.

thanks in advance..

Comment: you are loading header footer left right etc and what do you want to do after that? you want to load specific portions throught ajax? like footer header etc? please clarify your question properly

Comment: if your reason of using ajax is because of templating, you might want to check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957000/what-codeigniter-template-library-is-best

Comment: thanks for the response... but I am trying to use simple jquery .ajax() methods for page navigation...I don't know how to use it in an MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor to set your static header:

```
//in your controller

public $data;

function __construct()
{
    $this->data['header'] = 'static_header';
    $this->data['static_footer'] = 'static_footer';
}

function get_started(){
    if (test_login()) {
        $this->data['subview'] = 'login_nav/get_started';
    } else {
        $this->data['subview'] = 'errors/needlogin';
    }
        $this->load->view('template',$this->data);
}

function get_page(){
   $view = $this->load->view('your_dynamic_view','',TRUE);
   print json_encode(array('success' => TRUE, 'view' => $view);
}

// in your template.php
<div id="header"><?php echo $this->load->view('header');?></div>
<div id="subview"><?php echo $this->load->view('subview');?></div>
<div id="footer"><?php echo $this->load->view('footer');?></div>

// in your script - used to load dynamic view on you subview div
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('controller/get_page',{},function(data){
        if(data.success){
            $('#subview').html(data.view);
        }
    },'json')
</script>
```

Message me if there's a problem with my code 
Happy coding ---> :D

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [PinoyPal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15196317/8026137) is theoreticaly correct, but it didn't work for me in practice because it lacks one major detail: a route.

Take a look at this part of their script:

```
// in your script - used to load dynamic view on you subview div
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('controller/get_page',{},function(data){
        if(data.success){
            $('#subview').html(data.view);
        }
    },'json')
</script>
```

Here in place of **'controller/get_page'** there should be a url for an actual GET request. This is how it is generally supposed to look:

```
$("a.your_navigation_element_class").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //this is to prevent browser from actually following the link
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.get(url, {}, function(data){
        if (data.success){
            $('#subview').html(data.view);
        }
    },'json')
});
```

Now here's a question: where will this GET request end up? In the default controller route, that's right. This is why you need to 1) modify your request url and 2) set up a route, so that this request will be passed to an ajax-serving controller. Or just add an ajax-serving function to your default controller and re-route ajax requests to it.

### Here follows how it should all look wrapped up

In ...\application\controller\Pages.php:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
    ...
    public function serve_ajax ($page) {
        $view = $this->load->view($page, '', TRUE);
        print json_encode( array('success' => TRUE, 'view' => $view);
    }
    ...
}
```

In ...\application\config\routes.php:

```
...
$route['ajax/(:any)'] = 'pages/serve_ajax/$1';
```

On your page:

```
...
<body>
    ...
    <div id="page"></div>
    ...
    <script>
        $("a.navigation").on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            $.get("/ajax" + url, {}, function(data){
            //The trailing slash before "ajax" places it directly above
            //the site root, like this: http://yourdomain.com/ajax/url
                if (data.success){
                    $('#page').html(data.view);
                }
            },'json')
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

And you're all set.